# Dynamics 365 WebAPI - How to get user access to an entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

How can I retrieve the user access for an entity using Dynamics Web API? I am using v9.0

ie; Check if a user have read / create / edit access for an entity.

Comment: What do you mean by “module” - sales, service??

Comment: No..Accounts, Contacts, Leads etc

Comment: They are called Entities

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

These web api endpoints will help you to understand the things & achieve what you want.

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/systemusers(3bd2aded-20b2-e911-a98e-000d3a374b53)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.RetrieveUserPrivileges()

https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/privileges?$select=name
```

For ex. When I pass my System User GUID to the first function - the second url result says I have Global (Organisation) level Create privilege.

```
{"Depth":"Global","PrivilegeId":"a8bff87f-0df0-41d4-babd-f093faf1e32c","BusinessUnitId":"b08c8c6c-5c20-e511-80f7-c4346bac59ac"}

{"@odata.etag":"W/\"101387508\"","name":"prvCreateContact","privilegeid":"a8bff87f-0df0-41d4-babd-f093faf1e32c"}
```

**Glossary**:
Basic (User)
Local (Business Unit)
Deep (Parent: Child)
Global (Organisation)